# Is it use defined outside of the array range in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, defined

I am tring to find out the neighbours of an element in a 2Dmatrix,by checking horizontal and vertical neighbours.

Since I am fairly novice in Perl I thought this would work:

```
foreach $value2 ( 0 .. $#AoA ) {
    foreach $value ( 0 .. $#{ $AoA[value] } ) {
        unless ( defined $AoA[$value2][ $value - 1 ] ) {
            $0 = 0;
        }
        else {
            $0 = $AoA[$value2][ $value - 1 ];
        }
        unless ( defined $AoA[$value2][ $value + 1 ] ) {
            $1 = 0;
        }
        else {
            $1 = $AoA[$value2][ $value + 1 ];
        }
        unless ( defined $AoA[ $value2 - 1 ][$value] ) {
            $2 = 0;
        }
        else {
            $2 = $AoA[ $value2 - 1 ][$value];
        }
        unless ( defined $AoA[ $value2 + 1 ][$value] ) {
            $3 = 0;
        }
        else {
            $3 = $AoA[ $value2 + 1 ][$value];
        }
        print " $4 - $3 - $2 - $1\n";
        $neighbours{ $AoA[$value2][$value] } = [ $0, $1, $2, $3 ];
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

But I got an "Modification of a read-only value attempted at H:\Perl\voorlaatste_labo.pl line 51, <> line 47." error.
Is it actually possible to check neighbours this way ?
Or are there better implementations to try this?

Comment: First of all - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings`. Secondly - don't use `$1, $2, $3` etc. like this - they have special meanings, and are really bad variable names.

Comment: Please, avoid `unless ... else ...` use `if ... else ...` for better comprehension

Comment: Indeed. "unless" can be harder to understand, outside of very limited idioms (such as `next unless $condition` ). `if ... else` or even `if not ... else .. ` is much more comprehensible.

Comment: *Since I am a novice to driving in the snow, I thought hammering nails into my tires would turn them into snow tires!* I am having a *very* difficult time imagining the thought process that lead to thinking `$3 = 0`.

Comment: Well, you do get assignments where someone does a  regex test and then assigns `$2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is - `$1, $2, $3` etc. are values with special meanings - most especially `$0` as that's your process name (as seen in `ps`).

Don't change those, use sensible variable names.

You should also ensure you `use strict;` and `use warnings;` - this can avoid some real 'gotchas'.

I suspect you'll be being tripped up by `$value2-1` - because if `$value2` is zero, then... it's evaluating as `-1` which is actually the *last* element. Is that what you intended?

Otherwise I can't quite tell, because your error message says 'line 51' and your code snippet is only 34 lines long. Which line is actually having the problem?

I will guess it's this one:

```
foreach $value ( 0 .. $#{ $AoA[value] } ) {
```

Because you've omitted a `$` and therefore are not doing what you think you're doing.

`strict` and `warnings` would have told you this.

```
print " $4 - $3 - $2 - $1\n";
```

probably isn't going to be doing a lot of good either, because ... `$4` will be undefined here. (at best - it might not be, depending on whether you've run a regex recently or not, which is why it's a bad idea).